# React single line component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Hello I have a component which doesnt return anything. Im following a tutorial and the person is using newer syntax which confuses me a bit. The component looks like this:

```
const Alert = ({alerts}) => alerts !== null && alerts.length > 0 && alerts.map(alert => (<div key={alert.id} className={`alert-${alert.type}`}>{alert.msg}</div>));
```

I simply want to know how to write this without it being single line. So i can see what's going on.  Much appreciated in advance. For as far as i am aware you always need to return something.

Comment: Put line breaks in? Or break up the logic into reasonable chunks (essentially a guard clause) and if it gets past that return the alert mapping? What's the specific issue?

Comment: This does return something. It basically checks if any alerts exists. If so, it returns a `div`(s) containing the alert message(s).

Comment: Follow another tutorial, dont seem like instructor is doing any good by using one liner to its readers/students

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const Alert = ({ alerts }) => {
  if (alerts !== null && alerts.length > 0) {
    return alerts.map(alert => (
      <div key={alert.id} className={`alert-${alert.type}`}>
        {alert.msg}
      </div>
    ));
  }
  return null
};
```

Things at play here are:

1. Arrow Functions
2. Array.Map
3. JSX
4. Template Literals

Basically its a component that takes in an `alerts` property (Array) as a prop (`<Alert alerts={[...]} />`). It checks whether the passed array is present and is not empty and then maps over it. For every item in the array, we are rendering a `div` containing the alert message.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unrelated, but I'd treat the guard clause as an explicit guard clause, e.g., flip the logic around. Guards are "gateways" to the mainline code.

Comment: @DaveNewton you should explain that in your answer, otherwise, it's just a code snippet.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thats right, but the OP asked us to simplify their given code, adding something from my side could have problems in understanding. In my opinion.

Comment: @AjayGupta *shrug* IMO making guard clauses "stand out" from the mainline code *is* a simplification, and in this case, makes the logic easier to understand.

Comment: @DaveNewton Makes sense. Will keep that in mind. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

Very roughly (i.e., untested):

```
const Alert = ({alerts}) => {
  if ((alerts === null) || (alerts.length === 0)) { 
    return null
  }

  return alerts.map(alert => (
    <div
      key={alert.id}
      className={`alert-${alert.type}`}
    >
      {alert.msg}
    </div>
  ))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const Alert = ({alerts}) => {
  if (!alerts || !alerts.length) return null

  return (
    <>
      {alerts.map(alert => (
        <div key={alert.id} className={`alert-${alert.type}`}>{alert.msg}</div>
      )}
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: The fragment is useless. You can return an array directly.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are struggling with is generally the one-liner syntax, which doesn't need a return if there are no braces present. 
What I mean is that this line

```
return alerts.map(alert => {
  return (<div key={alert.id} className={`alert-${alert.type}`}>{alert.msg} </div>)
})
```

Would be the same as this line

```
return alerts.map(alert => (<div key={alert.id} className={`alert-${alert.type}`}>{alert.msg} </div>))
```